# How to implement message Acknowledgement in smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have successfully implemented one to one chat in my android application. Now i want to know my message is delivered or not. I googled my problem but unable to find any solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use ReceiptReceiveListener in Smack.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment implements ReceiptReceivedListener {

    @Override
    public void onReceiptReceived(String fromJid, String toJid, String receiptId, Stanza receipt) {
        if(isAdded()){
            // Check if the receiptId equals to the receipt you have sent.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried this. I have added message packed id in outgoing message and received it but unable to understand what to do with that id ??

Comment: In my code, the id is for checking which message is the one should be marked as "received". Let's say there are 100 messages on your chat view, and the app receives 100 receipt for each of the messages on this view, so you need to know which one should be marked as "received" once you get one receipt. And the receiptId is just for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry. I am little bit confused. In my list view there is not unique field/id's along with particular message. So please tell me how to generate dynamic id so that i can mark particular message as delivered on receiving acknowledgement ?

Comment: id it's automatically generated by SMACK in Message object

Comment: @begginer yes, as MrPk said, it is generated in the Stanza

Comment: Yes, it is, but let assume 2 outgoing message has been lost out of five, and there are 3 incoming message acknowledgement receipt id. then how can i know which message should be marked as delivered ?? I am not storing dynamically generated id anywhere ...

Comment: Okay, please give me some time and I will write a post to explain it on my personal blog. I will let you know after it's done, maybe tomorrow or tonight.

Comment: @begginer hope this helps you. https://medium.com/@rui.geng/how-to-mark-the-message-is-received-by-using-smack-in-android-462a91d0d936#.qnbft5rvw

Comment: @RuiGeng Thanks!  i will try to implement it. Sorry but today i noticed another strange problem. Suppose that i have recently sent message to user A, and then i want to send message to user B. when i am sending my message to user B, it will not send to user B, but it will send to user A. i mean to say my message is received by recently contacted user (in my case user A). But i can see in my log the receiver JID has been changed from user A to user B, But message is still receiving by user A.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: @begginer I would say could you please check if there is anything wrong with the server..? If the JID is correct, maybe something wrong on your server side.

Comment: @RuiGeng can you please tell me what things should i check on my server ?

Comment: @begginer this is what I am guessing, just check why the jid is correct the server send the chat message to another person.

Comment: @RuiGeng Thanks for your useful answers . I just solved my problem by disconnect and reconnect my client .

Comment: @RuiGeng is it also possible via StreamManagement? I am able to get server acknowledgements but cannot find anything to receive acknowledgements from the end client, thanks.

Comment: @SarthakMittal , server ack. in sense? are you able to get ack form server for incoming message? Let say If user A sending msg to user B then first user A getting any kind of ack from server that his msg is received by server or not ?

Comment: @Radhey did you find any solution for server acknowledgement while user A sending message to user B